# Проблема Scapy на windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, vmware, виртуальная-машина, сниффер

[image: скрин с ошибками]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установил scapy на windows 10 и по-моему что-то много чего не работает. И пакеты не отправляются. В чем проблема?
Будет ли он работать из-под виртуальной машины? На линуксе пишут с ним удобнее работать.